# java: package myList does not exist

Tags: java

This is a exercise my teacher gave us. Why does list not exist?

```
import javafx.application.Application;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class so{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add("Steve");
        list.add("Pete");
        list.add("John");
        ListIterator<String> iterator = new list.listIterator();
        iterator.next();
        iterator.next();
        iterator.add("Remo");
        iterator.previous();
        iterator.previous();
        iterator.remove();
        System.out.println(list);
    }

}
```

error msg: Error:(20, 51) java: package list does not exist

Comment: Remove the "new" before list.listIterator

Answer (score 2):

```
    ListIterator<String> iterator = new list.listIterator();
```

should be

```
    ListIterator<String> iterator = list.listIterator();
```

the new keyword is used to create a new Object. Right now you don't want to do that. You have a LinkedList object , namely called "list".

To retrieve your ListIterator you want to call a method on the list object which is done without using the new keyword.

So list.listIterator() is the correct syntax.

Comment: You are welcome. If the question is answered please accept the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers